# Optional object prop fails to read when specified the key returned from a function

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Here's the gist of the code, and you can try it [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAysCuAzRUC8UDeAoKUwCcB7MAfgC5MBtAZ2HwEsA7AcwF0LaGWBfLXrAMaFGtKAEMKcJCnQZ+QkcCgAjSQmRpMOPETAUMAcgDWEEAYoGAbmIA28CAd79E8RgOD1hUZhGABpUwAKAEoOOiZmLVx8X3h8RigDakIAWwgTMz4sQWFRDLCuSPQk1PTTA2ysZQA6AmIoADIGlVrdSgzWKtb6ppa6sEoffyDg1igAenG0AD4oAHcACxAAQlWgA). why's this failing?

```
type Stuff = {
  prop?: {[string]: string}
}

const a: Stuff = {}

const b: Stuff = {
  prop: {'key': 'value'}
}

function getKey(): string {
  return 'somekey'
}

const key: string = 'somekey'


b.prop && b.prop[key]
b.prop && b.prop[getKey()] // => fails!!
```

the error message is like this

```
// 19: b.prop && b.prop[getKey()] // => fails!!
                        ^ Cannot get `b.prop[getKey()]` because an indexer property is missing in undefined [1].
// References:
// 2:   prop?: {[string]: string}
//             ^ [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The FLOW error here is a little misleading.

The problem is that `Stuff.prop` is an optional param in your type. Turn this into a required param, and it works as expected.

The reason is because when you make it optional, `Undefined` becomes a valid type for prop, meaning that any reference to prop as a variable will fail. Yes, even though you have already tested that it exists.

Honestly, I don't know how to make this work in FLOW while having prop be optional. If anyone knows how, I am very interested.